# Nuitka creating .dist folder without any exe file on MacOS

Tags: deployment, pycharm, exe, nuitka

I am trying to use nuitka to package a project I have in PyCharm, however when I run it in creates the .build and .dist directories, but inside the .dist directory there is no .exe file where is should be located.

My main file is called gui.py, when I run `python3 -m nuitka --standalone --enable-plugin=tk-inter gui.py` in the terminal it works and tells me that the gui.dist and gui.build files were created. The gui.exe should be inside gui.dist, but when I look it's not there. For context, I am using a mac. I have seen several tutorials and followed them exactly, everything I do looks the same and produces the same output save for the missing .exe file. Additionally, I tried the `--onefile` command and still could not find a .exe for my project.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Macs, but in many cases they are similar to Linux. In Linux, look for a .bin rather than a .exe for your executable file. Windows uses .exe.